# Print data fetched from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php

  $koneksi = mysqli_connect('mysql.idhostinger.com','root','pw','db');
  $result = mysqli_query($koneksi,'select * from posting');

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

    for($x = 0; $x <= count($row); $x++) {
      echo "<div style='background:green'>$row[$x]</div>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Hello guys! This code takes data from mysql, then prints it in a div container, wrapped with a div too.

**The problem is** that every row of data captured produces 2 div.

How to get each row to produce only and only 1 div?

Thank you.

Comment: row contains 2 values as result of your query. Write `select one_field from...`

Comment: Can you tell us something about structure of the posting table? Your code produce a new div for every column in every row.

Comment: the table just have 1 column in each row

Comment: Please include your SQL results (of the `select * from posting`) when run from a query tool, such as mysql cli, phpmysql, or mysql workbench.

Comment: you can check the result here http://nurul.hol.es/tampil.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `div` for each *item* in each row:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))  {
    for($x=0;$x<=count($row);$x++){
        echo "<div style='background:green'>$row[$x]</div>";
    }
}
```

If you want a single `div` for the "row" and to put all items in that `div`, put the `div` in the loop that iterates over the rows:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))  {
    echo "<div style='background:green'>";
    for($x=0;$x<=count($row);$x++){
        echo $row[$x];
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo` line is executed by `while` and `for` loop, you just `echo` it in `while` loop well help you.

**Thanks**

```
 <?php
 $koneksi = mysqli_connect('mysql.idhostinger.com','root','pw','db');
 $result = mysqli_query($koneksi,'select * from posting');
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
 $div = "<div style='background:green'>";
 for($x=0;$x<=count($row);$x++){
 $div .= "<p>$row[$x]</p>";
}
 $div .= "</div>";
 echo $div;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($x=0;$x<=2;$x++){
echo "<div style='background:green'>$x</div></br>";
}
```

every number have div ..

if u want put all number in one div :

```
<div style='background:green'>
<?php
for($x=0;$x<=2;$x++){
echo $x;
}
?>
</div>
```

or if u want pull data from other way like js, just get text from hidden div and pull to "#div" .html() or .text()

Answer (score 0):

Although you are just doing a simple `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME`, still it is very much advised to use PDO for so many reasons which you might personally want to research. With this approach in mind; here is what may help in this context:

```
    <?php
        // USING PDO HAS SO MUCH ADVANTAGES OVER mysqli + mysql EVEN IN SIMPLE CASES LIKE SELECT *

        $HOST       = "mysql.idhostinger.com";      // CHANGE TO YOUR HOST
        $USER       = "root";                       // CHANGE TO YOUR USERNAME
        $PASS       = "pw";                         // CHANGE TO YOUR PASSWORD
        $D_BASE     = "db";                         // CHANGE TO YOUR DATABASE NAME

        try {
            $dbh            = new PDO("mysql:host=$HOST;dbname=$D_BASE", $USER, $PASS);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);              

            $stmt           = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM posting");
            $status         = $stmt->execute();
            $results        = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $arrData        = array();
            $strOutput      = "<div class=''>" . PHP_EOL;  //<== AN OUTER DIV TO HOLD ALL CHILD DIVS: THE ONES CONTAINING THE ROW-DATA.

            if($results){
                foreach($results as $intKey=>$result){
                    // BUILD THE OUTPUT IN THE FOREACH LOOP USING A VARIABLE
                    // AND THE COLUMN NAME...
                    // HERE $columnName IS THE SAME AS THE NAME OF YOUR 
                    // TARGET COLUMN IN THE DB-TABLE (EG: `post_content`)
                    // THAT IS: $result->post_content   ;-)
                    $strOutput .= "<div style='background:green'>{$result->columnName}</div>" . PHP_EOL;
                }
                $strOutput .= "</div>" . PHP_EOL;         //<== CLOSE THE OUTER DIV
            }
            // YOU CAN NOW ECHO THE OUTPUT ANYWHERE.... MUCH MORE FLEXIBLE, HUH?
            echo $strOutput;

            //GARBAGE COLLECTION
            $dbh        = null;

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

This PDO Approach (in this Scenario) may appear a lot verbose (and it arguable seem like that) but on the long run, it really is worth it...